# Adjustable absolute axis labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, positioning

How can I use absolutely placed y labels, but still adjust the absolute placement? In the below example, I want to be able to get the two plots to align exactly, including the y labels.

If I add

```
ylabel absolute,
```

to the list of arguments of

```
\begin{axis[
```

I cannot use

```
ylabel shift = 0.1cm,
```

in the same argument list. If I skip ylabel absolute, I can use ylabel shift, but then I have to use different values for yshift (and it is not obvious exactly which values) to get equal spacing. Ideally, I would like to first fix the position of the y label (as ylabel absolute does) and then shift it (as ylabel shift does). How can that be done?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=6cm,
        width=9cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot[smooth,color=blue]
      plot coordinates {
        (0,3)
        (2,4)
        (3,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{One curve}

    \addplot[smooth,color=red]
        plot coordinates {
            (0,0)
            (1,2)
            (2,1)
            (3,0)
        };
    \addlegendentry{Another curve}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=6cm,
        width=9cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot[smooth,color=blue]
      plot coordinates {
        (0,3)
        (2,4)
        (3,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{One curve}

    \addplot[smooth,color=red]
        plot coordinates {
            (0,-10)
            (1,2)
            (2,1)
            (3,1)
        };
    \addlegendentry{Another curve}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `ylabel absolute, ylabel style={yshift=1cm}` to shift the labels. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted to do. Is ylabel shift=1cm an old command, and ylabel style={yshift=1cm} the one to replace it?

Comment: `ylabel shift` can result in a different direction for the shift compared to `yshift`. Clearly, `yshift` simply shifts upward or downward, but `ylabel shift` shifts along "the outer normal vector". Try it for a 3D axis to see the difference.

Comment: @Jake Please write your comment here up as an answer

Comment: Christian Feuersänger, thank you for your comment, I saw it just now. @Jake If you make your comment an answer, I will make it an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ylabel absolute, ylabel style={yshift=1cm}` to shift the labels.